# Exception while getting application icon android 8, works on android 7

Tags: android, kotlin, android-8.0-oreo, android-7.1-nougat

I'm trying to get the large icon for the notification in android app like that:

```
val bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
```

It works correctly in android 7.1, but throws exception in android 8:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: bm must not be null
```

It is the same code, nothing changes. Does someone know whats wrong?
I'm using Kotlin(if it matters).

Comment: It´s because `val` can´t get values from object which can be set to null. You need to wrap it on optional so there is every time something present but maybe with no inner value. Or just use `var bm: <type>?` - the `?` does it make to allow NULL references.

Comment: the problem is not that `bm` could be `null`, its because on android 7.1 is not and in android 8 it is `null`

Comment: Do you have `mipmap-anydpi-v26` in your `res` directory?

Comment: yes, I have `mipmap-anydpi-v26 `, but it has only xml-s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `R.mipmap.ic_launcher` is not an id of `BitmapDrawable` resource. 
`ic_launcher.xml` file from `mipmap-anydpi-v26` directory is used on Android 8 instead of `ic_launcher.png` from `mipmap-*dpi`. It contains adaptive icon resource.

You may try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46018816) to convert it to a `Bitmap`.